# iOS - Subclassing UIControl to make a custom switch - how to detect on/off?

Tags: ios, uiswitch, uicontrol

I'm using this class to make a custom switch: https://github.com/robertchin/rcswitch

It subclasses UIControl. I can switch it on and off, but how do I detect this in the code? UISwitch has a .on property that I can check when the value changes, but UIControl doesn't have that.

Comment: post some code from your implementation, there are a lot of different ways you can create a switch

Comment: Dear lord, that GitHub code is incredibly complicated just for implementing a switch.

Comment: @jrturton do you know of an easier way to use customizable switches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [header file](https://github.com/robertchin/rcswitch/blob/master/Classes/RCSwitch.h) for the `RCSwitch` class, there is an `on` property, so you should be able to use `mySwitch.on`. Alternatively you could use `[mySwitch isOn]` as the getter has been specified in the property declaration.

Comment: Thanks. I should have noticed that.